# Endorsed cheque

Tags: canada, check, fraud, contracts

I am trying to understand the underlying contract of an endorsed cheque a bit better, and would love to know how the liabilities are determined in the following situation:

Alice writes a cheque to Mallory over 100 CAD. Mallory endorses the cheque to Dave. Now Mallory goes back to Alice and claims the cheque has been lost. Alice writes Mallory a new cheque, and Mallory cashes the cheque.

Dave is a bit slow and tries to cash his endorsed cheque now. It has been stopped. Dave goes to his favorite lawyer and asks him what to do.

I can think of a few possibilities:

1) The cheque is a valid contract between Alice and Dave, and a court can order Alice to pay Dave the amount of 100 CAD.

2) The liabilities follow the endorsement. That is Alice owes Mallory 100 CAD, and Mallory owes Dave 100 CAD (and usually a bank short-fuses this chain of liability).

3) Alice and Mallory are jointly liable. If Mallory is bankrupt, Alice would owe Dave 100 CAD.

4) Since Mallory committed fraud she is liable. If Mallory is bankcrupt, Dave will get nothing.

5) There is no precedence and a judge would have to come up with something to sort this out.

Note the malicious behavior happens after the cheque has been endorsed to Dave. It happens in Canada. I am afraid I do not understand http://laws.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/B-4/FullText.html well enough to sort this out myself.

I am interested in an argument or an authoritative reference. Of course, I also appreciate your opinion.
I am happy to clarify, if I use the wrong terminology.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal not a financial question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a persona finance issue that the OP is facing, and also more about a legal issue ("Who is liable?") than a money matter.

Comment: Cheques are still used widely in north america, and understanding the potential (even theoretical) implications of drafting a cheque seem relevant to personal banking.

Comment: While checks ('Murica) are indeed still used, your question is about the legality of using or redeeming checks rather then a personal finance approach. There's some overlap, but the question is better suited for https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I see the overlap with law. If the question is indeed off-topic, is there a way to migrate it over to law.stackexchange?

Comment: I believe best bet is to flag for Moderator Intervention and ask that it be migrated. Or delete the question and post a new one there.

Comment: well... "The cheque is a valid contract [...]"  The check is not a contract, it's payment.  Probably payment related to a contract of some sort, and probably could be used to substantiate the existence of an unwritten contract, but the check is not, itself, the contract. Contracts are separate from payment.  Alice owed Mallory $100, and has paid it.  Mallory owes Dave $100 and apparently has not successfully paid it, what check goes to who doesn't really matter, as long as everyone is ultimately paid what they're owed.

Comment: @quid To say, a cheque is merely an instruction to your bank to pay the other party, is a perfectly fine answer. I guess, that would mean that Alice is not obliged to pay Dave. But I got the impression that with drafting a cheque you also are responsible to honor it (otherwise it would be fraud). So it seems a bit more than just an instruction to your bank.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Is there a rule here that questions must be about a personal financial issue that someone is actually facing at the instant that they post the question? That general questions and hypothetical questions are not allowed?

Comment: @mna, sure but the money was already owed in relation to some agreement, which it why the check was written in the first place.  The money was owed irrespective of the check, but now there may also be a fraud component.

Comment: @quid Alice and Dave never communicated, so there is no agreement between them, beside what is implied by the endorsed cheque. My understanding is, if Mallory did not ask for another cheque Alice would have to pay Dave the money.

Comment: Correct, Alice and Dave have nothing to do with each other because the check was endorsed by Mallory... And again, Mallory and Dave already had a contract requiring payment in place, but in addition to the $100 Mallory already owed Dave, there may also be a fraud component.  The check is not the contract, the contract already existed and the check is payment on the contract.

Comment: @Jay According to the [money.SE tour page](https://money.stackexchange.com/tour), "Focus on questions about **an actual problem you have faced.** Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do" while the Help page says "You should only ask practical, answerable questions **based on actual problems that you face**. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." (emphasis added)

Answer (score 2):

I was taught in school -- in the United States -- that liability is reverse order of the endorsements. When Dave tries to cash the check, if the check was stopped or it bounces or whatever, Mallory is liable as the most recent endorser.